# Should properties that mean the same thing be considered different properties?

Tags: properties

Is the property of "being an even number greater than 0 but less than 4" be considered the same as "being a number less than 4, an even number, and being positive"

In a sense, these properties are redundant but described differently.

Comment: Yes, they have the same extension but differ intensionally.

Comment: Aren't "greater than zero" and "positive" the same in meaning, ultimately? So in the theory of propositions (as sentence-level meanings), for example, "Snow is white," and, "Schnee ist weiss," are not taken for different propositions, but different names for the same proposition. Now if properties are lexical meanings, one imagines that different names for the same property do not make for a difference in that property itself (though they make for different properties *of names* themselves, the properties of the different words used).

Comment: Answers should be given as answers. Comments should be suggestions for improvements of the question.